# positively homogeneous function that differentiable at $0^k$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, special-functions

Let $f:\Bbb R^k \to \Bbb R$ be continious function and positively homogeneous function with degree $\alpha$ in $\Bbb R^k \setminus {0^k} $

(the definition of  positively homogeneous function in our course is $f(\lambda\cdot x)=\lambda^\alpha \cdot f(x)$ for $\lambda > 0$  and x $\neq 0^k$)

if $\alpha > 1$ and $f(0^k)=0$ **prove** that f is differentiable at $0^k$

**note**:
the definition of differentiability at $0^k$ in our course is
$lim_{h\to 0^k}$ $f(0^k+h)-f(0^k)-\nabla f(0^k)\cdot h \over |h|$ = $0$

I succeeded in proving that $∇f(0^k) = 0^k$, which means that with the data $f(0^k) = 0$ What is left to prove is $lim_{h\to 0^k}$ $f(0^k+h) \over |h|$ = $0$

The question is taken from an old exam in Calculus 3

Comment: Please [provide context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960): where does the question come from, and what have you tried in order to solve it?

Comment: I provided the details, Thanks

Comment: Thanks , you meant from $f(x) = \lambda^\alpha \cdot x$ *to* $f(x) = \lambda^\alpha \cdot f(x)$ right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure it is not $f(\lambda x) = \lambda^\alpha f(x)$ and $\alpha >1$ ?
Without my first suggestion, the definition is weird. Furthermore, with the first suggestion but not the second, the function $|x|^\alpha$ should satisfy the hypotheses, but it is not differentiable at $0$.

By making those two changes, you can say that if $x$ is not equal to $0$, then $|f(x)| =||x||^\alpha |f(x / ||x||)|$. Furthermore, $f$ is continuous, and is hence bounded on the unit ball since it is a compact since we work in finite dimension. Hence,  $|f(x)| \leq M ||x||^\alpha$. Thus, $|f(x) - f(0)| =  |f(x)| = o(||x||)$, which is the definition of being differentiable at $0$ with null derivative.

Comment: Correct, it is supposed to be $\alpha >1$. However, can you implement the homogeneous property with variables? (rather then Constants like $\lambda$)?

Answer (score 1):

Since $f$ is continuous and homogeneous of order $\alpha>1$, $f(\mathbf{0})=0$.

$$f(\mathbf{0}+\mathbf{h})=f(\mathbf{h})=|\mathbf{h}|^1|\mathbf{h}|^{\alpha-1}f\big(\frac{1}{|\mathbf{h}|}\mathbf{h}\big)
$$

This can be rewittten as
$$f(\mathbf{0}+\mathbf{h})=f(\mathbf{0})+\mathbf{0}\cdot\mathbf{h}+r(\mathbf{h})$$
with $\lim_{\mathbf{h}\rightarrow\mathbf{0}}\frac{r(\mathbf{h})}{|\mathbf{h}|}=0$. FRom the definition of derivative, we find that $f$ is differentiable at $\mathbf{0}$ and that $f'(\mathbf{0})=\mathbf{0}$.